# How should I name my tables/classes in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, naming-conventions, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I am working on a pro sports stats website and I'm looking for advice on how to setup my tables as well as naming my classes (models/controllers).

Let's say for example that I'm working with data from the NBA, NFL and MLB.

Would it make sense to setup the tables with prefixes such as `nba_players`, `nba_Stats`,`nfl_players`, `nfl_Stats`,`mlb_players`, `mlb_Stats`?

Would it make more sense to just have them as separate databases such as `NBA.players`, `NBA.stats`, `NFL.players`, `NFL.stats` etc...

This leads me to my next question of setting up my classes.

I want to make sure I setup everything with CakePHP conventions in mind. It would seem to me that if I went with the prefix method I suggested above, that I would name my controller something like `NbaPlayersController` and my model would be `NbaPlayer`. Would I need to use the `$tablePrefix` as outlined here => http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1060/tablePrefix? I'm guessing I wouldn't but I'm just not 100% sure.

If I did things the latter way with having separate DB's, I'm guessing I would have to have separate apps unless there's another way to do it that I'm not aware of.

Also, the data for the NBA, NFL and MLB are so different and there will be tons of different stat categories and such that I don't want to consider combining them into individual tables such as `players` and `stats` and then having a `league_type_id` to determine which league I want info for. I think that way would just be too combersome and add a lot of extra space to the db that would be unnecessary.

So I guess my question is, is one of the methods I listed above the preferred way of doing things in Cake or is there another way that I should be doing it that I haven't listed above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for more than one database and no need to have separate tables for different player types - they're all still "players".  Just keep the stats each in a different table.

Your structure should look something like this:

**Tables:**

- players
- leagues
- leagues_players
- mlb_stats
- nfl_stats
- nba_stats

**Models / Associations:**

- Player hasAndBelongsToMany League
- League hasAndBelongsToMany Player
- MlbStat belongsTo Player
- NflStat belongsTo Player
- NbaStat belongsTo Player
- Player hasOne MlbStat
- Player hasOne NflStat
- Player hasOne NbaStat

Comment: As stated above, I really don't want to mix players from different leagues into the same tables for various reasons. But it looks like I was on the right track as far as how I wanted to name my tables and classes.

Comment: @bigmike7801 - There is NO reason IMO to go with separate "players" tables for each league, since they're all "players" and are going to have the same exact table structures (or they should anyway), not to mention a player CAN be in more than one league, even if it's rare.  Your STATS are what differ - hence having different tables for each set of stats.  (the reason you gave for not wanting tables split players/stats was due to "tons of different stat categories and such" - hence my solution takes that into account.)